# Dynamic div height that increases UP in size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Might be a silly question, but does anyone know of a way for `position: fixed` divs at the bottom of an element (say, the body) to increase *up* in size as content is dynamically added? Something like `anchor: bottom` or `increase: up`?

I imagine that some type of JavaScript solution is the only real option for such functionality, correct?

Just thought it was worth a quick check from the collective expertise here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioning it on the bottom should do the trick

```
style="position:absolute; bottom: 0px;"
```

Working JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KwD8J/

Comment: with container set to position:relative

Comment: it's been a long few days :)
Many thanks. What I'm really trying to work through is using css transitions for a `bottom: 0` widget to toggle it up on click... but that's of course another question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Without reading any further into your question, I believe all you need is `bottom: 0px;`

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zL9Tw/